# Laravel get with one to many relationship's relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have models like that:

```
User
Order
Status
```

`User` has many `Orders`, and `Order` has one `Status`

Now what I am trying to do is to write something like that:

```
$user = User::with("Orders" => function($query){ 
                            $query->with("Status"); 
                        })
```

I get `User` with `Orders` but `Orders` don't have `Status` relationship inside, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the relations like this

```
$users = User::with('Orders')->with('Orders.Status')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I think what I am doing is pretty same

Comment: This should work, post your models relationships so we can check and also make sure that you have records on your database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `status` function within your `Order` model, and then simply eager load it like this:

```
$users = User::with('orders.status')->get();
```

Comment: but I don't have order, I have orders

Comment: @O.Shekriladze see my edit. And make sure that your function in the User model is called `orders`.

Comment: Like that I will lose order data, but this doesn't work too.

Comment: Make sure that you put enough info to your question, because from what you described this will work 100%, nothing will be lost.

Comment: yes query was right, the problem was in something else

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the relations like this

```
$users = User::with('orders.status')->get();
```